# Run Command Prompt Commands list excel or txt

Tags: cmd

Is there any way If so how would I do the following

How to get (excel or text)list of folders having same file?

I have already tried using `>dir /s /b > print.txt`

Comment: Can you be a little more precise about the expected output please ?

Comment: `dir /s /b *.xls *.txt>print.txt`?